# React with Typescript: Types for array.map() with arrow function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to js/ts but experienced in C#. Now I'm learning React and want to use typescript. I try to add types to this demo project: https://github.com/bradtraversy/projectmanager/tree/master/src .

```js
export interface IProjects {  
  projects: IProjectItem[];
}

export interface IProjectItem {  
  title: string;
  category: string;  
}

class Projects extends React.Component<IProjects,object> {    

  constructor(props: IProjects) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {    
    let projectItems = this.props.projects.map( project  => {
      return (            
        <ProjectItem project={project} /> //Error: the type "{ project: IProjectItem; }" is not assignable to "Readonly<IProjectItem>"
      );  
    });
    ...
}

class ProjectItem extends React.Component<IProjectItem,object> {    
 ...
}
```

What I thought is that "project" within the arrow function is of type "IProjectItem" and that's the right type for the component "ProjectItem".
It seems I'm doing something wrong with the used types. 
I only have added types to the example mentioned above as video from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A71aqufiNtQ ( @ ~ 21:06 )
What are the right types using the given example?

Comment: I don't know React well but maybe `return (<ProjectItem project=project />)`? It seems like it doesn't like you wrapping the `IProjectItem` in an object.

Comment: tha's not the Probelm, curly braces are jused in .jsx/.tsx files for marking js code within html. It works like done in the linked video tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current ProjectItem class doesn't accept as its props a `project`
 object, but its props are defined by the IprojetItem interface (i.e. it accepts `title` and `category` as props).

Instead of

```
class ProjectItem extends React.Component<IProjectItem,object> {    
     ...
}
```

You should write

```
export interface ProjectItemProps {
  project: IprojectItem;
}

class ProjectItem extends React.Component<ProjectItemProps, object> {    
 ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, just to understand it right: 
When I map this.props.projects.map( project => ... )
the type of project is IprojectItem.

But when I use IProjectItem as first generic type of a Component : It does *not* mean, that the property parameter of this component
needs to be a object *implementing this interface* ( like it would be on C# or java?)

Comment: Yes it does, but you're missing the point here. Whatever gets passed as first type of `React.Component<A, B>` (i.e. as `A` here) will define the props interface for this component. You don't want the props to be a, `IProjectItem`, you want the props to _accept_ one property named `project` that'll have the `IProjectItem` type. Got it ?